# HTML Tidy: how to set 'force-output' to 'yes'?

Tags: html, xml, tidy

I am using HTML Tidy in the command line environment for Windows. I need to force the conversion of some html files to xml, even if there are errors.

I do the following steps:

- create a file "conf.txt", whose content is:
  `force-output: yes`
- type the following command line:
  `tidy -config conf.txt  -o filename.xml  filename.htm`

However, no "filename.xml" gets generated. Note I am able to get an output XML file from the same 'bad' HTML file when using the online version of tidy at http://infohound.net/tidy/tidy.pl.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Never mind! I actually figured out a way around:

**tidy --force output yes -o filename.xml filename.htm**

Thank you to all the people who read the question!

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a way:

```
tidy --force output yes -o filename.xml filename.htm
```

Comment: Thanks, spent 2 hours on this, including thinking about recompiling `tidy`